# Nhibernate Auditing

Tags: nhibernate, auditing

I have a question about auditing. Most auditing examples use one audit table to track changes. However, we need one audit table per "regular" table. In other words, tblCustomer would also have tblCustomer_History. I can't figure out how to use a listener, and on update populate the history table as well. Any ideas? I'd hate to fall back on SQL Server triggers.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to build your own audit solution, maybe you should have a look at NHibernate Envers?
https://bitbucket.org/RogerKratz/nhibernate.envers